# Adding filter and subfilter to category

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, filter

i have a working category view page.
but after adding filters and sub filters to the category. in the view page my products are not shown when clicking on the filters.

i tried consoling, it shows all filter working, even when I console on clicking a filter it give the correct value. so the only problem is all products disappear after clicking a filter

```
import { getFilteredProducts } from '../a/product';

import { getCategory } from '../a/admin';

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    category: match.params.categoryId,
  });
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    category: match.params.categoryId,
  });

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState('');

  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState(null);


 const loadFilteredResults = async (page) => {
    console.log('Fetching products with filter:', filter); // Log filter before API call
    try {
      const res = await getFilteredProducts(filter);
      console.log('Request filter:', filter); // Log request URL
      console.log('Request URL:', res.config.url); // Log request URL
      console.log('Request Method:', res.config.method); // Log request method
      console.log('Request Body:', JSON.parse(res.config.data)); // Log request body (if applicable)
      console.log('Response from API:', res.data); // Log response from A
      setProducts(res.data);
      if (res.data.length > 0) {
        setCategoryName(res.data[0].category.name);
      }
      console.log('sending to:', res.data); // Log response from A
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching filtered products:', error);
    }
  };
  


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await getCategory(match.params.categoryId);
        setCategoryData(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching category data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchCategoryData();
  }, [match.params.categoryId]);

  
  const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, checked } = e.target;
    console.log('Current filter state:', filter); // Log current filter state
    const updatedFilter = checked ? { ...filter, [name]: value } : { ...filter, [name]: '' };
    console.log('Updated filter:', updatedFilter); // Log updated filter state
    setFilter(updatedFilter);

    console.log('Sending filter to server:', updatedFilter);

  };



  useEffect(() => {
    loadFilteredResults(1);
  }, [filter]);



 let checkActive = products.some(function (product) {
    return product.status === 'active';
  });




const renderFilters = () => {
    console.log("categoryData:", categoryData);
    return (
      categoryData &&
      categoryData.filters.map((filter) => {
        console.log("Filter:", filter);
        return (
          <div key={filter._id}>
            <h3>{filter.name}</h3>
            {filter.options && filter.options.length > 0 ? (
              filter.options.map((option) => (
                <div key={option}>
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name={filter.name.toLowerCase()}
                      value={option}
                      onChange={handleFilterChange}
                    />
                    {option}
                  </label>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <div>Subfilters not available</div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })
    );
  };
```